# Copying sources from one maven project to another

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, dalvik

Am trying to copy sources from a maven multi-module web project to a maven-android project. This needs to be done as the sources (which I want to keep outside of the android project for another platform) need to be compiled under Dalvik in order to be run on android. Aside from that, dependencies are not packaged when running on android, but the need for compiling using Dalvik overshadows this limitation.

The closest documentation of the issue I found [here](https://groups.google.com/group/maven-android-developers/browse_frm/thread/a0cdfbee685e73f1/833f006b5044f9b1?tvc=1&q=unpack#833f006b5044f9b).

Am using mvn dependency:unpack to unpack the sources to the android project in eclipse. Prior to this I need to run mvn install to install the sources to the local repository. Then I have to refresh the eclipse android project.

The ideally scenario would be for this to work directly with m2eclipse without the three step manual process.

Would appreciate any inputs.

Thanks
sfk

Comment: This works with the latest version of m2eclipse 1.0. crowne's answer might have worked with the earlier version of m2eclipse although I didn't try it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest lifting the common sources out of the web-project into their own project.
The new project should be configured to produce two artifacts:

1. normal jar file : for inclusion in the multi-module web app
2. apkLib : for inclusion in your android projects

This could be done by defining a secondary attached artifact with in the maven naming [co-ordinates](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) (groupId:artifactId:packaging:classifier:version).

see http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib

Comment: Hi. thanks for answering this. Meant to try this out earlier but never did get around to it. It does seem like the right answer but I can't really figure how to do it. Can you please update the answer with an example. Thanks